# SVG stroke inside fill

Tags: svg

I'm making svg animation and i have to end up with stroke inside fill or as just one line without that messy transformation. I'm using `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` to animate and also change `fill` from `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)` to `color`
My question is:
Can I force stroke to appear inside of shape?

Comment: Not directly, but you could make the shape smaller to achieve that effect.

Comment: Yeach but that doesn't make in my case :/ I mean i couldnt maki it smaller

Comment: You could use a clip-path to clip the outer part of the stroke.

Comment: There's `outline-offset`, too (and it can be set to negative values, so the outline is inside). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline-offset